# How to use java 7 TLS 1.2 on spring running on Liberty Profile

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, java-7, tls1.2

I would like to ask how could I use or enable TLS 1.2 since the web services I am upgraded to TLS 1.2. I could no longer create a session to the said web service.

How do I use TLS 1.2? Do I need to convert my code(s)?

Below are the technologies currently I use:
* Ubuntu 15
* IBM Java 7 x64-71
* Eclipse x64 - WAS Liberty Profile
* MySQL
* Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE
* Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE
* Hibernate 4.3.5.Final

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem, my Liberty application responding with TLS v1.0 but I wanted to use v1.2.

By default Liberty (at least up to v.8.5.5.8) uses TLS v1.0 (sslProtocol="SSL_TLS").

To enable v1.2 you should, in server.xml, specify sslProtocol="SSL_TLSv2".

For example add the following line, using your own keystore:

`<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" sslProtocol="SSL_TLSv2"/>`

Comment: Add that line to what file?

Comment: To the server.xml file.